# Show DisplayName Lables in ADB2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have a set of localized displayname variables in our Custom Policies for ADB2C, such as...

```
<LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="signInName" StringId="DisplayName">Email</LocalizedString>
```

These then render in our UX as the below.

[image]

Is there a way to tell ADB2C to put the labels on top of the fields or in some other orientation?

Thank you - Greg.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do things completely in B2C, you could create custom claim types emailLabel and passwordLabel with user input types Paragraph (or ReadOnly, but I prefer Paragraph), put them as input claims with default values set to whatever you want the label to say, then use the labels as display claims, where their order should affect the order they appear in.

If you are good with HTML and CSS, I'd just create the labels in a custom content definition and use that instead